# Get EF Table by type (parameter)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have this very old database with all the tables named like this `ANAGT*postfix*` and all the columns are namede like this `*prefix*_*column name*`.

I have to query all the tables with the same query more or less, but obviously the names of the columns are all different so I would have to do some trick with a sql statement with the strings, but I prefer to get a strong typed exception in case of errors using the EF.

So I've created some interfaces and implemented them on partial classes from the EF model

```
public partial class *table name* : IIdentificable, ICountabile {}
```

`IIdentificabile` means that there's a method with a common name that gets all the ids (instead of query `*prefix*_ID`), so when I'll have to query the table I'll just have to do

```
var result = from elem in myContext.[Table]
             where elem.GetId() == 1
             select elem;
```

I've created a generic method that gets all the types from a certain interface (`IIdentificable` for instance) and now **I have to get the EF table by type**.

```
var tablesType = typeof(myModel).Assembly
                .GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t=>t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)));

foreach(Type t in tablesType){
    var query = from elem in myContext.GetTable(t) //and here's what I can't do
                select elem.GetId() == 1
                select elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach may be better. In the EF Model you can rename the C# Objects and properties. Using the properties of a selected property in the model, you can change the Name to get rid of the prefix. Similarly, the properties of a selected table in the model allow you to change both the Entity Set name (the name of a collection of them) and the Name of the C# class. The names of the underlying database tables and columns aren't affected.